How to startActivityAndCollapse(PendingIntent) from quick settings on locked screen of Android 14?
I want to show an activity when the users taps on a quick settings tile while the screen is locked. This works as expected using the startActivityAndCollapse method taking Intent as parameter  (deprecated in API level 34).
public class MyTileService extends TileService {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        this.startActivityAndCollapse(intent);
    }
}

The activity still appears using the method taking a PendingIntent as parameter (added in API level 34), but I have to unlock the device to get the activity shown.
public class MyTileService extends TileService {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    appContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            );
            this.startActivityAndCollapse(pendingIntent); //have to unlock
        } else {
            this.startActivityAndCollapse(intent);
        }
    }
}

Just for completeness a snippet from MainActivity:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    setShowWhenLocked(true);
}

The first code example shows the activity on my locked Android 14 device.
The second example forces me to unlock the device after tapping on the quick settings tile.
How can I prevent the latter still using the PendingIntent api?

Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?
